# What happens when you receive a trade token while your inventory is full?

Tags: clash-royale

Not long ago, trade tokens were introduced in Clash Royale.  You can hold up to 5 of each unique trade token. The trade tokens can be found in the clan war loot bag, or they can be purchased from the shop.

What happens if you have 5 of a trade token and you get another from clan war loot or purchase one from the shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [wiki article on trade tokens](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_Tokens); the last bullet point has the information you are looking for.

> If a player already has 10 tokens of a rarity, further tokens received
>   from Special Event Challenges, Global Tournaments, and Clan War Bounties will be converted
>   to Gold (250 for Common, 500 for Rare, 1,000 for Epic and 2,000 for
>   Legendary). Tokens refunded by canceling a trade or purchased in the
>   Shop can surpass the limit without being converted to Gold.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if they come from Challenges, Shop and maybe even Global Tournaments they go over the limit.
If it comes from a War Bounty, however, it gets converted to Gold.